# CAROUSEL não alinhado com a NAVBAR

Tags: carousel, nav-bar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: Imagem]

**texto em negrito**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Projeto Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">História</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisar">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/04/123660610_3557923067584996_8189977501809062468_n.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/03/bn_destaque_home_carto.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/03/08-DESK-OUTUBRO.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não alinha onde? Me parece centralizado certinho, seu problema não ficou claro

Comment: Gostaria que ele ficasse alinhada igual a primeira foto...obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara é só vc tirar a `nav` de  dentro dessa estrutura de `container > row > col`, pois essa estrutura tem alguns `padding` e `margins` do grid do Bootstrap, algo que vc não precisa nessa situação!

Isso está descrito na documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#containers

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Removendo o  `container`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima, comentei no código as tag dispensáveis

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Projeto Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <div class="container"> -->
    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
      <!-- <div class="col-12"> -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">História</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisar">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <!-- </div> -->
    <!-- </div> -->
  <!-- </div> -->

    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/04/123660610_3557923067584996_8189977501809062468_n.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/03/bn_destaque_home_carto.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images-americanas.b2w.io/spacey/acom/2020/11/03/08-DESK-OUTUBRO.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @AlexFlausino de nada jovem! Se a resposta resolveu o problema considere marca-la como aceita clicando nesse ícone ✓ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta. Assim ela não fica em aberto mesmo já tendo sido resolvida ;)